# What is the difference between .vec and .sca output in Omnet++?

Tags: c++, simulation, omnet++

What is the difference between .vec and .sca output files in Omnet++ simulator? And, by your experience, when/how should I use one rather than the other?

Answer (score 0):

According to [OMNeT++ Simulation Manual](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ana-sim:config-results):

> Simulation results are recorded into output scalar files that actually hold statistics results as well, and output vector files. The usual file extension for scalar files is .sca, and for vector files .vec.

When the simulation records a scalar value (i.e. single value), it goes to a `.sca` file. And when a vector (i.e. values over time) is to be recorded, a `.vec` file is used.
As a consequence **the user does not have to bother about which file will be used**. Moreover, the result display in OMNeT++ by default scans both types of file and presents every scalar and vector that are found.

Answer (score 0):

Vector files show every event that happened
Scalar is more of a summary of all the events that happened.

I prefer using Vector files as I can nitpick the values I want to do analysis.

You can try TicTok part 5 to better understand the difference between the files.
https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/part5/